# Javascript send an id with a text value

Tags: javascript

I have this input :

```
<input name="customer_id" type="text" id="customer_input">
```

Can I send a different value than what it is written in the input?

Example :
The input displays `John Doe` but when I submit the form it sends the value `20` ?

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you could share some code of your attempt so far?

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't very clear. The whole code is working. Can I send a different value than what it is written in the input? ex I write John Doe but I send 20 when submitting

Comment: you can take the value `onsubmit` and convert it using whatever logic you wanna, but we don't know what u want since u ONLY showed us an input tag

Comment: I know that I could use some logic and search in the database... the only code you need to understand the problematic is the input.

Comment: @ben-ju you can try using a hidden input field.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that. If there is no "easier" solution I'll try this thanks @PranavRustagi

Comment: Is that "different value" related to something? Where do you take it from?

Answer (score 0):

```
function customer(){    
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: $('#formId').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data);

            }
        });
}
```

*On submit form it can send all data to the api*

Comment: There is no mention of use of an API.

Comment: it dosent matter if it api or php file

Comment: It is just a simple form and the solution can be achieved without using an XHR request, by using hidden input field. :)